# how to use @class in a string with MVC4 Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, yql

I have an MVC4 Razor application where I need to construct a string in a javascript section containing @class.  How can I escape to use that in the string?

```
var S = 'select * from html where url=\"www.yahoo.com\" and xpath=\'\//div[contains('@class,\"techSpecsTable/\")]\' '
```

how do I escape @class?

Comment: You don't need to escape `@class`, what you need to escape is your apostrophe before `@class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the @class by doing

```
@@class
```

but I think you need to excape the '

```
var S = 'select * from html where url=\"www.yahoo.com\" and xpath=\'\//div[contains(\'@class,\"techSpecsTable/\")]\' '
```